# To get column value from specific rows using c# and convert to xml by linq

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've got a data table like

[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojf3F.png)

Now I have to get the value of the first two rows, and column 1 has the name of the element, and column 2 has the value of the element in xml using c# linq

after that,skip to 4th row and from 4th row to n rows ,i want all values dynamically passed into element (element name i will hard code it)

note : Element means xml element
required output :
[file.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFIn1.png)

Comment: Please show the definition of your `DataTable` in code. Images are too hard to transcribe.

Comment: thanks @Richard  for your response...but i have found solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this My datatable ---- for datatable check the above image
//Result is my dataset which i got from my xlsx file and i converted dataset to datatable.

 DataTable dt = result.Tables[0]; //Table[0] -- is my 1st sheet of xlsx file

 var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(2); //Taking first 2 rows

 XElement xml1 = new XElement("ROOT",
                from r in rows
     select (
     new XElement(r.Field<string>("Column0"),r.Field<object>("Column1"))
            )
            );
//Field<object>--object is datatype which takes anytype of value from columns or rows in data table

 var n = result.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

 var Ref = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(3).Take(n-3);

  XElement xml2 = new XElement("ROOT",
                from rs in Ref
                select (
                   new XElement("References",
                      new XElement("A", rs.Field<string>("Column0")),
                 new XElement("B", rs.Field<string>("Column1")),
                 new XElement("C", rs.Field<string>("Column2"))));

//Now merge those two xmls
var x1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1.ToString());
var x2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2.ToString());
x1.Root.Add(x2.Root.Elements());
x1.Save(@"D:\filename.xml");


For output check my question...
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you want to get column value from specific rows and convert to xml file

by linq.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
        var result1 = table.AsEnumerable().Take(2);
        var result2 = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(3).Take(table.Rows.Count - 3);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("product.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.WriteStartElement("DFS");
        foreach (DataRow item in result1)
        {
            createNode(item[0].ToString(), item[1].ToString(), writer);
        }
        foreach (DataRow item in result2)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("References");
            createNode("A", item[0].ToString(), writer);
            createNode("B", item[1].ToString(), writer);
            createNode("C", item[2].ToString(), writer);
            createNode("D", item[3].ToString(), writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
```

[image]